# Store HashMap values into database when value is null

Tags: java, mysql, exception, null, spring-data

I have to store my `HashMap<String,Object>` into database MySql through Spring data.
To retrieve data from HashMap I use key value and it may happen that the key doesn't exist and in this case I have to avoid to store into database with set method because I convert value into String or int or float and in this case java throws null exception.
Given that I have a lot of row to store into database, I wouldn't like to use If clause on all the line of code, but how can I do it?

```
@Override
public void archiveAcquisition(HashMap<String,Object> rowValues, int index) {
        switch(index){
        case 1:
            firstRowValues=rowValues;
            break;
        case 2:
            secondRowValues=rowValues;
            break;
        case 3:
            thirdRowValues=rowValues;
            break;
        default:
            actualRowValues=rowValues;

            AvoidNullValueError(ExcelMappingCoordinate.shift,index);

            Shift shift=new Shift(actualRowValues.get(ExcelMappingCoordinate.shift.getCoordinate()+index).toString());
            shiftServices.create(shift);
            MissionProfile missionProfile=new MissionProfile(actualRowValues.get(ExcelMappingCoordinate.missionProfile.getCoordinate()+index).toString());
            missionProfileServices.create(missionProfile);
            DpfWeighting dpfWeighting=new DpfWeighting();
            dpfWeighting.setUnladenWeight((float)actualRowValues.get(ExcelMappingCoordinate.unladenWeight.getCoordinate()+index));
            dpfWeighting.setGrossWeight((float)actualRowValues.get(ExcelMappingCoordinate.grossWieght.getCoordinate()+index));
            dpfWeighting.setDpfTemperature((float)actualRowValues.get(ExcelMappingCoordinate.dpfTemperature.getCoordinate()+index));
            dpfWeightingServices.create(dpfWeighting);
            OilSample oilSample=new OilSample();
....
....
```

for example I done

```
if ((value=actualRowValues.get(ExcelMappingCoordinate.unladenWeight.getCoordinate()+index))!=null)
                dpfWeighting.setUnladenWeight((float)value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you meant, but my idea is adding the following helper method to your class:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 <V> void ifPresent(Map<String, Object> map, String key, Consumer<V> consumer) {
    V value = (V) map.get(key);
    if (value != null) {
        consumer.accept(value);
    }
}
```

Then instead of writing

```
dpfWeighting.setUnladenWeight((float)actualRowValues.get(
ExcelMappingCoordinate.unladenWeight.getCoordinate()+index));
```

you can use the `ifPresent` method like this:

```
ifPresent(actualRowValues,
ExcelMappingCoordinate.unladenWeight.getCoordinate()+index,
dpfWeighting::setUnladenWeight);
```

and this way the `dpfWeighting::setUnladenWeight` consumer won't be invoked if the value in the map is `null`

Comment: yes , I would like to implement the if clause above in one method. I think that your methos is correct, but if 'if (value != null)' I have to cast to String, int or float depends on setMethod